# ImageView + ListView + GridView - Scrolling works only with ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, uiimageview, scrollview

I wrote xml file that show imageview then listview then gridview .. the imageview doesn't scroll up .. only the listView scrolls and the gridview doesn't appear at all

I tried using ScrollView .. but it also doesn't work it shows the listView and GridView with very small height and the imageView doesn't scroll

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
         >


<RelativeLayout 
    android:id= "@+id/child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/car_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fortuner_2011"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/car_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/car_image"
        ></ListView>

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/carPics"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/car_info"
        ></GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your `ImageView` as a header to the `ListView` and your `GridView` as a footer.

Comment: how can I put the gridView as a footer ?! .. it gives me error